# get ticket response intuit

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform

I am doing a application in which i have to setup a payment gateway using intuit,
i have followed https://developer.intuit.com/docs/030_qbms/0010_hosted_paypage/0020_quick_start_guide

and have all the things done and now i am getting proper response via url

for example,

if i paste https://paymentservices.ptcfe.intuit.com/paypage/ticket/create?AuthModel=desktop&AppLogin=drive2wellness.www.drive2wellness.com&AuthTicket=SDK-TGT-37-SUQ9i1ehMMzS2JIN1jrPNw&TxnType=Sale&Amount=10.10

in my url i will get appropriate response from server

like

```
Ticket=77+977+9EO+/vWzvv73vv73vv71iXQxiYC7vv73XtjNQEe+/ve+/ve+/131007071809vVLvv70477+977+977+9K++/ve+/vSJNVn8T77+977+977+977+9LtS/
OpId=Ie--vWVhJ---ve131007071809--ve--vRE0LO--
StatusCode=0
StatusMessage=OK
```

which gives me Ticket and OpId that i'll use in to send another request to server,

But My question is how exactly can i get the Ticket and The OpId and store them to variable so i can forward them..???

any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvr mind i got the answer with

```
$response = file_get_contents($url);
```